# Topologic Entropy of the the free-square flow S

Tags: analytic-number-theory

someone knows how to prove that $\eta(n)= \mu^2(n)$ and a-fortiori μ(n), is not deterministic? I'm prove that the system associated to the flow $(X_S,T_S)$ is ergodic, where $X_S$ ís a closure the $T_S$-orbit of $\eta$ in $\{0,1\}^{N}$, but still I did not get to prove that a topologic entropy is $\frac{6}{\pi^2} \log 2$ like ensures Sarnak on his lecture about the ramdomness and Dynamic of the Möbius function. Any suggestion for to calculate this entropy?

Comment: How do you define this entropy? What does "the $T_S$-orbit of $\eta$ in $\{\,0,1\,\}^N$" mean?

Comment: Seja $(X,d)$ um espaço topológico compacto. $F=(X,T)$ um fluxo, então a entropia topológica se define por
$$ h(F) = \lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \limsup \limits_ {n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log  N(n,\epsilon)}{n}$$ where $N(n,\epsilon)$ is a higher cardinality of a subset E of X satisfying $$d_n(x,y) = \mbox{máx}\{d(T^i(x),T^i(y)): 0\leqslant i <n \} >\epsilon$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the notation you are using comes from Sarnak's lecture on [Möbius randomness and dynamics](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Mahler%20Colloquium%20Lecture%204%20-Mobius%20randomness%20and%20dynamics.pdf).

In that case, the result you are looking for appears as Theorem 10 on page 9 of this paper of Sarnak: [Three Lectures on the Mobius Function Randomness and Dynamics](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/MobiusFunctionsLectures%282%29_0.pdf).

Comment: thanks, but a proof if this result is'nt on the lecture. He said that is proven in the lecture 3, I still did'nt find this lecture, do you know where is it?